# Change how home and end keys work in XCode

Tags: xcode

When I press the End key I expect it to bring me to the end of the line. Likewise when I press the Home key I expect it to bring me to the beginning of the line. In Xcode though, these navigate to the top and bottom of the page. How can this be changed?

Comment: Cmd+left arrow, or Cmd+right arrow. Enjoy. (Yes I know not an answer to your question, but, when all else fails...)

Comment: Consider changing it in wider set of apps at once: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/remap-home-and-end-to-beginning-and-end-of-line

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings > Text Key Bindings**

Then find these two:

- Move to beginning of line
- Move to end of line

Assign <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> to these respectively.

If you're doing this, don't forget to update *Move to Beginning/End of Line Extending Selection*, too and assign <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>, respectively. This will continue the desired behaviour when you have <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> pressed.

You will also have to remove the conflicts that appear.

FYI: <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> are the way things are normally done on a Mac. If you are coming from Windows I would try to adjust to this. If you want to jump between words, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

Comment: I was using the hard way on my Mac Laptop. I think they do that because the small keyboard doesn't have Home and End keys. Since I'm now running Hackintosh on my PC, I have those keys, so I plan to use them.

Comment: See also: *Move to **Beginning/End** of Line Extending Selection* and assign `Shift+Home/End` to keep text selection consistent with those keys as well.

Comment: You have single handedly saved Xcode for me! +10 if I could.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you.  My blood pressure goes up everytime I Fn-Left arrow and XCode jumps me away from my work, unlike most other editors

Comment: Another example of how Apple stuff is just soooooo easy! Ugh.

Comment: @RoatinMarth This `Shift+Home` will move the top section of the selection... If my current selection position is lower (let's say I did `Shift+Down` first), then press `Shift+Home` it will not bring my end selection to the beginning of the line, but the start selection at the beginning of the line. What a mess...

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer a thousand more times - I was going crazy.

Comment: this is so close to restoring normal input behavior, but like jsgoupil says - "Move to Beginning/End of Line Extending Selection" moves the carat in a weird way that is unlike literally every other mac app, whether you're using command-arrow or home/end

Comment: Second the +10 @CJohnson... also agree in theory with OP that trying to switch would be ideal but we use PCs exclusively at work so the "bindings" are essentially permanent in motor memory

Answer (score 4):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences... -> Key Bindings, tab Text Key Bindings, and change them to whatever you want.

Comment: How ???  Went there, identified Move to End of Line, selected it, pressed End and...it scrolled me to the end of the list...?!?!?! Damn it, Apple...

Comment: LE: nevermind...selection needs to happen to the far right, and it will take the key binding...

Comment: Florin, look at "Move to End of Text"/"Move to Beginning of Text" keys

Answer (score 2):

If you're after 'smart home', where pressing the Home key takes you to the start of the text on that line, and a second-press takes you to the start of the line... then you'll be wanting this:

https://github.com/insanehunter/XCode4_beginning_of_line